# Google maps block on contact page is giving offsetwidth error and messing up other modules in drupal 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, drupal, drupal-7

I have a working website running Drupal 7 with a few standard modules installed like views, panels and colorbox. Everything was working fine and I started creating a custom module with google maps to show a location on a map with a custom marker.

The map is working as intended and I didn't notice anything wrong until I went into my views admin. Somehow the JS code from the Gmap is messing up the config area of some of my modules. (Pop ups not working properly, buttons misplaced etc.)

EDIT:
When I enable this module the console displays "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null" in main.js from google maps api I think.

Here is the code from the .js file:

```
(function ($) {
"use strict";
Drupal.behaviors.simple_gmap = {
    attach: function (context) {
         function initialize() {
    // Map options.
            var location = new google.maps.LatLng(51.5550390, 5.0843100);
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 17,
                panControl: false,
                zoomControl: true,
                scaleControl: false,
                qw2mapTypeControl: false,
                rotateControl : false,
                overviewMapControl : false,
                scrollwheel : true,
                center: location,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                disableDefaultUI: true
            };

    // Build the map and marker.
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
            var image = 'sites/all/modules/simple_gmap/images/icomaps.png';
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: location,
                icon: image,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                title: 'Testtitle'
                });
    }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    }
};
```

})(jQuery);

I went over the code, but honestly i'm not sure what to look for. Thanks in advance for any help!

EDIT:
When I enable this module the console displays "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null" in main.js from google maps api I think.

EDIT:
After some hours searching the best answer I found was that the map div is not being rendered before the javascript runs that needs to access it. I also read that (function ($) {} and drupal.behaviors in the js code are supposed to wait for the page to load. So I don't understand why it would give me that error.

Comment: Sounds like a css conflict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working with some help at the Drupal forum! Gonna try to explain it here so it might help others figuring out this problem.

I was using a custom .module file that included the .js file I posted up top.
Code from my .module file:

```
function simple_gmap_init() {
   drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'simple_gmap') . '/simple_gmap.js');
   drupal_add_js('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false', 'external');
}

function simple_gmap_block_info() {
   $blocks['simple_gmap'] = array(
      'info' => t('Google Map'),
      'cache' => DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_ROLE,
);
return $blocks;
}

function simple_gmap_block_view($delta = '') {
   $block = array();
   switch ($delta) {
      case 'simple_gmap':
      $block['content'] = '';
}
return $block;
}
```

My .module file created a div with id "map_canvas" wherever I placed my block. I added this block to my contact page, which added the div ONLY on that page, but the .js file was being included in the head of every page. This caused the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null" on every page but my contact page. Which broke my javascript in other modules.

This error was caused by my modules .js file looking for the "map_canvas" div, which was not present on any of the other pages.

What I did to solve the problem was include my .js file ONLY on the contact page where the "map_canvas" div existed.

I added the code written below at the bottom of the .module file:

```
<?php
   function simple_gmap_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
   {
      if($form_id == 'contact_site_form')
      {
         $form['map'] = array
         (
            '#markup' => '<div id="map_canvas"></div>',
            '#weight' => -20, // adjust as necessary
            '#attached' => array
         (
         'js' => array
         (
            array
            (
               'type' => 'file',
               'data' => drupal_get_path('module', 'simple_gmap') . '/js/some_file.js',
            ),
           ),
          )
         );
        }
       }
     ?>
```

and I removed the code written below from the function simple_gmap_init():

```
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'simple_gmap') . '/simple_gmap.js');
```

This made sure the .js was only loaded on my contact page and not on any other page.
Also make sure you give the "map_canvas" a width and height in the css so it displays.

I've seen a LOT of posts last 2 days about this problem while searching for an answer and I hope this can help someone out. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try reordering the JS files.
It might be that a js file is loaded before an other file is loaded that is needed.
For example, jQuery beeing loaded after jQuery functions are called.

Comment: Tried putting the JS file all the way under the footer. But still the same issue.